# How to set an object in Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an object which I am trying to set in the firebase but not able to do so. Bellow code runs without an error but there is no *coursesinterestedin* field in the firebase forge.

Controller code -

```
  $scope.filterA = {
      coursesInterestedIn: [{ "eng": "What's", "ukr": "Що є" }, { "eng": "your", "ukr": "твоє" }, { "eng": "surname?", "ukr": "прізвище?" }]
  };

  $scope.register = function () {
    Auth.register($scope.user).then(function(user) {

      var abc = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.filterA));

      console.log("This is it: -----> "+abc);
      return Auth.login($scope.user).then(function() {
        user.studentname = $scope.user.studentname;
        user.studentphoto = $scope.user.studentphoto;
        user.studentmobile = $scope.user.studentmobile;
        user.email = $scope.user.email;
        user.fathername = $scope.user.fathername;
        user.occupation = $scope.user.occupation;
        user.fathernumber = $scope.user.fathernumber;
        user.coursesinterestedin = abc;
        user.studentclass = $scope.user.studentclass;
        user.studentstream = $scope.user.studentstream;
        user.studentschool = $scope.user.studentschool;
        /*user.studentcourse = $scope.user.studentcourse;*/
        user.studentacademic = $scope.user.studentacademic;
        user.studentabout = $scope.user.studentabout;
        user.username = $scope.user.username;
        user.password = $scope.user.password;
        return Auth.createProfile(user);
      }).then(function() {
        $location.path('/');
      });
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.error = error.toString();
    });
  };
```

Service code -

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
...
createProfile: function (user) {
  var profile = {
    studentname: user.studentname,
    studentphoto: user.studentphoto,
    studentmobile: user.studentmobile,
    email: user.email,
    fathername: user.fathername,
    occupation: user.occupation,
    fathernumber: user.fathernumber,
    coursesinterestedin: user.coursesinterestedin,
    studentclass: user.studentclass,
    studentstream: user.studentstream,
    studentschool: user.studentschool,
    /*studentcourse: user.studentcourse,*/
    studentacademic: user.studentacademic,
    studentabout: user.studentabout,
    username: user.username,
    password: user.password,        
    md5_hash: user.md5_hash
  };
  var yoref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'profileForStudents');
  var yoprofileRef = $firebase(yoref).$asObject();
  return yoprofileRef.$set(user.uid, profile);
},
```

I get the following error in my console:

```
logged out
collegeauth.js:63 logged out
2auth.js:69 Happened and copied
auth.js:72 This is the complete object [object Object]
auth.js:73 Object {coursesInterestedIn: Array[0]}
auth.js:62 logged out
collegeauth.js:63 logged out
auth.js:93 This is it: -----> [object Object]
auth.js:37 @logins service College name is: kjb
auth.js:38 @logins service College email is: a@a.com
auth.js:55 logged in
auth.js:58 Object {provider: "password", uid: "simplelogin:171", id: "171", md5_hash: "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930", email: "a@a.com"…}
collegeauth.js:56 logged in
collegeauth.js:59 Object {provider: "password", uid: "simplelogin:171", id: "171", md5_hash: "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930", email: "a@a.com"…}
angular.js:9778 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Auth.createProfile (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/auth.js:31:27)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/auth.js:111:21
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11319:81)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11405:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12412:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12224:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14023:36
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4300:10)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4601:7
auth.js:55 logged in
auth.js:58 Object {provider: "password", uid: "simplelogin:171", id: "171", md5_hash: "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930", email: "a@a.com"…}
collegeauth.js:56 logged in
collegeauth.js:59 Object {provider: "password", uid: "simplelogin:171", id: "171", md5_hash: "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930", email: "a@a.com"…}
```

Comment: That last experiment fails for the correct reason: `$asObject()` returns a `$FirebaseObject`, which doesn't have a `$set` method. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject  Can you remove that part from your question, so it doesn't distract anyone?

Comment: Does you `FIREBASE_URL` end with a `/`? If not, you're missing a `/` in `var yoref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'profileForStudents');`.

Comment: Aside from that, it works in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/copaq/1/edit?js,output. If you can't get it to work with the above hints, can you set up a jsbin/jsfiddle/plunker that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Frank Edited the question as per the comment.
`FIREBASE_URL` was fine and ended with a `/`
I was able to successfully add the object in forge using the $save method instead.
Thanks for your help! :)